# How to fix cron schedule issue?

Tags: centos7

I tried to run this command manually and working fine

```
/var/www/html/crm/cron/vtigercron.sh
```

but when I schedule cron with the below to run automatically nothing happens

```
* * * * * root /var/www/html/crm/cron/vtigercron.sh
```

just gives me

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status crond.service
```

Comment: Try run two command: "systemctl status crond.service; sudo crontab -e". Write output here.

Comment: [root@issabel ~]# systemctl status crond.service -l
â crond.service - Command Scheduler
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/crond.service; enabled; vendor preset                                                                                        : enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-12-18 13:37:33 EET; 48min ago
Main PID: 2914 (crond)
   CGroup: /system.slice/crond.service
           ââ2914 /usr/sbin/crond -n

Comment: Dec 18 13:37:33 issabel.local systemd[1]: Started Command Scheduler.
Dec 18 13:37:33 issabel.local systemd[1]: Starting Command Scheduler...
Dec 18 13:37:33 issabel.local crond[2914]: (CRON) INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 70% if used.)
Dec 18 13:37:33 issabel.local crond[2914]: (root) BAD FILE MODE (/var/spool/cron/root)
Dec 18 13:37:33 issabel.local crond[2914]: (CRON) INFO (running with inotify support)
Dec 18 13:37:33 issabel.local crond[2914]: (CRON) INFO (@reboot jobs will be run at computer's startup.)

Comment: Dec 18 13:55:01 issabel.local crond[2914]: (root) BAD FILE MODE (/var/spool/cron/root)

Comment: What say?: ls -l /var/spool/cron/root

Comment: chmod 600 /var/spool/cron/root